# How to access bitbucket using app password

Tags: bitbucket

I have created an app password as explained [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/app-passwords-828781300.html)

But now, how do I access the repository using this app password?
What will be the url?
Can someone direct me to a page showing an example please?

The below is a code for github. How do I do it for bitbucket?

```
var githubToken = "[token]";
var url = "https://github.com/[username]/[repository]/archive/[sha1|tag].zip";
var path = @"[local path]";


using (var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
{
    var credentials = string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}:", githubToken);
    credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(credentials));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", credentials);
    var contents = client.GetByteArrayAsync(url).Result;
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, contents);
}
```

### Update

Go to **Personal Settings** and then **[App Passwords](https://bitbucket.org/account/settings/app-passwords/)** as shown below.

[image: Create Bitbucket App Password]

Comment: You ask about Bitbucket, but your code references `githubToken` and `https://github.com/`. Which system are you actually trying to use?

Comment: @Chris, github is only an example : The below is a code for github. How do I do it for bitbucket?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You can perform this request as follows:

```
curl -u "walery2iq:<appPassword>" "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/[yourRepo]"
```

Important thing here - use your username, not e-mail address.
Important because for login on bitbucket itself you are using e-mail and not username :D

You can find your username here:

> Settings -> Account settings -> Username

See picture.

[image: Use this username - not your mail address]

Comment: Username, not email address, was the key for me using the Bitbucket import UI. Thanks!

Answer (score 135):

Since the question was "how do I access the repository" - maybe this is useful for somebody:
You can also use a Bitbucket "App Password" to use Git over HTTPS.

```
git clone https://USERNAME:APP_PASSWORD@bitbucket.org/OWNER/REPO.git
```

(Or, if you want to avoid storing the password in plaintext:
Omit `:APP_PASSWORD` in the URL above, and just provide the App Password when prompted by Git.)

This may be useful for CI (although Git over SSH might be better).

Comment: IF you already cloned repository, use this `git remote set-url origin https://USERNAME:APP_PASSWORD@bitbucket.org/OWNER/REPO.git`

Comment: ok. It really isn't obvious.

You need to set your Remote URL/Path in SourceTree Settings as follows

https://<user-name>:<app-password>@bitbucket.org/path-to-source-master/src/master/

The user name is the main account user name, which is found under Bitbucket profile settings (Username) under Account Settings at https://bitbucket.org/account/settings/

The app password is set in https://bitbucket.org/account/settings/app-passwords/

Comment: Seems like this method is exposing the password in clear text..

Answer (score 76):

You need to create your "app password" on bitbucket console. Under your Avatar ->Personal Settings ->Access Management ->App Password. Create app password and note it down.

Once done, open your git bash and set the remote origin using -

```
git remote set-url origin https://<Your_Account_Name>:<App_Password>@bitbucket.org/<Your_Account_Name>/<Repo_Name>.git
```

Comment: In the last part, you are not required to give Account_name again instead need to provide a path for the repo. bitbucket.org/OWNER/REPO.git

Comment: this is the one that works for me. but maybe just a little correction: it should be https://<your_username>:<app_password>@bitbucket.org/...

Answer (score 20):

If you have a 2-step verification I was able to clone but not to make a push. This worked for me using git instead of curl:

```
git push https://<username>:<GENERATED-APP-PASS>@bitbucket.org/<username>/<repo>.git
```

Generate an app password at https://bitbucket.org/account/admin/app-passwords

Answer (score 8):

```
git remote set-url origin https://[app-label]:[app-password]@bitbucket.org/[your-repo].git
```

Comment: Did not work. Says invalid credentials after trying to push. Kunal Keshari solution worked. You need Account_Name instead of app-label. And you need to repeat it after bitbucket.org/

Answer (score 1):

Git uses `libcurl` under the hood so one might keep password in `~/.netrc` file:

```
machine bitbucket.org login USER password PAZZ
```

and avoid leaking password to shell history:

```
git clone https://$USER@bitbucket.org/$WORKSPACE/$REPO.git
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, check **use credential helper** from git settings.
That is, `preferences-> version control-> To git -> use credential helper`