# unable to read askpass response from '/home/.cache/Google/AndroidStudio2021.1/tmp/intellij-git-askpass-local.sh' in ubuntu Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm facing some issues in latest android studio i.e.,

1. Un-able to clone git
2. unable to read askpass response from '/home/.cache/Google/AndroidStudio2021.1/tmp/intellij-git-askpass-local.sh'

Android Studio version info :

Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-211.7628.21.2111.8139111, built on February 2, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.11+0-b60-7590822 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Linux 5.13.0-30-generic
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 1280M
Cores: 8
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true

Current Desktop: ubuntu:GNOME

[image]

Answer (score 1):

after several hours of research I found the best soultion for this I dont know this is the right way to use it or not. But its working fine.Additionally, you have to create app password if you are using bitbucket, As per their new update.[refer this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70920900/10209902)